# Show Database comment in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, comments

What is the mysql command where I display database comments?

**Show databases;** is not return comment

```
Database | comment
xpto     | xpto xpto sssss
```

Comment: -- will work as comment in mysql, You can further check here :http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-comment/

Comment: I don't think there is one.

Comment: Databases do not have comments. Only tables and columns do.